# How can i get data from form request with Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to get the form data information from the request by submitting a simple form page.

Form page:

```
    <form action="http://localhost:3000" method="post">
    <input name="name_lastname" value="Ercan Kaval">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I want to get the name_lastname information from here.

I'm trying to meet the post request at the end of payment.

Comment: You can do that in a couple of ways. The easiest one would be `v-model`. Also, what are you trying to accomplish? A bit more information would be appreciated and it would be easier for us to help. Otherwise, check the Vuejs Docs because this is not related to nuxt per-se

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information. I'm trying to meet the post request at the end of payment. @Zarko

Comment: This might help you with what you're trying to achieve. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: Using `v-model` and `submit` on form event listener is the way.

Comment: request come from outside the application @Amini

Comment: Well, @ErcanKaval are you trying to intercept a payment validation/response or something? How the request is coming from outside the application? Is it possible to provide a bit more code?

Comment: @Zarko Request post request from bank. How can I read the parameters contained in the form data